# Android: Mark images selected in gallery

Tags: android

I have an app that allows users to select images from the gallery (using an ACTION_PICK intent). I want to allow users to update their selection, by going back into the gallery and making changes. However, when they go back to the gallery for a second/third/etc. time, I want their previous selections to be selected in the gallery... Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Gallery app or your own activity containing a gallery of images?
If it's your own activity you can simply store the results of your ACTION_PICK into a [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You can then go through you gallery and mark your items as selected based on those stored preferences. 
I hope this helps

Comment: Hey Nelson, Thanks for the quick response. I actually meant the Gallery app. The idea is that the user picks a set of images from the Gallery app and *only these images* are shown in my activity which uses the gallery view. However, to update, the Gallery app is launched again, so it is the Gallery app in which I want to select images.